# Download all Gmail emails, regardless of spam

Tags: outlook, spam-prevention, gmail

We use Gmail's [Google Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps) for receiving our work emails. Our users don't use the web client to access their emails, they use Outlook.

The problem is, some emails are being marked as spam inside Gmail and are staying in the spam folder, and don´t get received by Outlook.

Is there a way to download Gmail's spam mails and mark them as spam from Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

Can you use IMAP rather than POP for your client access? If you can then you will be able to view all of your Gmail folders in your client of choice, including the spam folder and move emails between them. As far as I am aware though you will not be able to tell Gmail that this mail is not spam for future use.

Comment: In the anti spam team of GMail there are quite a bunch of smart people. I'm sure they are using the fact of someone moving a mail out from the Spam IMAP folder (and all other conceivable information) to better detect what the user considers spam. So I do think this counts as marking the mail as not spam.