# Download spam from Gmail account

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, backup

I want a simple way to download all the messages in the Spam folder in my Gmail account. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just spam or including the spam folder?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12545/download-all-gmail-emails-regardless-of-spam

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Thunderbird, clicking Ctrl-A in the spam folder and save.